# How to add Ubuntu Desktop's default packages after completing a "Minimal Installation"?

Tags: software-installation, minimal-install

When I installed Ubuntu 19.10, I chose the "Minimal Installation" option. I figured that the default programs (that are regularly installed with Ubuntu) would be accessible from some meta-package afterwards, but I have yet to find it.

**Is there such a meta-package or other way to install the default Ubuntu 19.10 programs without re-installing whole system?**

Comment: Are you familiar with how to use apt?

Comment: @user535733 Yes. I'm just hoping I can do something like `apt install ubuntu-full` instead of `apt install thunderbird transmission rythmbox...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [metapackage](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=ubuntu-desktop) you seek is `ubuntu-desktop`.

This will give you most of the stock Ubuntu Desktop, minus some applications:

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

This will give you the complete stock Ubuntu Desktop with all applications installed from the Desktop image:

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop --install-recommends
```

Comment: `ubuntu-desktop` is already installed. And I don't think it includes the default apps like `transmission` and `rythmbox`.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

First, open the terminal and enter

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
```

Next, enter this command, this will install most of the apps and packages which are installed with the normal installation.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't quite answer the question. This will only install the recommended packages (in addition to the required ones) of that meta-package if that is configured in the Apt settings, which you shouldn't assume. Anyway, the full answer has been submitted by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Based in other responses but using other strategy:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xorg xterm`
3. `sudo apt install --install-recommends firefox`
4. `sudo apt install --reinstall --install-recommends ubuntu-desktop`

Maybe the 1 and 4 are enough, but I put the other dependencies if needed.

Additional Links:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages
- https://wiki.debian.org/DesktopEnvironment